# Python relative imports testing my sanity

Tags: python, python-import

**EDIT**: A circular dependency issue was the reason why `from .. import auth` didn't work, see my own answer below. Cheers to all.

---

I'm dabbling with relative imports in Python while reorganizing some code and what should have taken 10 minutes is now taking untold amounts of time. Here's my file structure:

```
project/
       /__init__.py
       /application.py
       /lib/
           /__init__.py
           /auth.py
           /utils.py
           /views/
                 /__init__.py
                 /login_view.py
                 /test.py
```

In `login_view.py` I have:

```
from . import auth
```

which yields: `ImportError: cannot import name auth`

However this works:

```
from ..auth import untoken, req_auth_or_error
```

Which I don't understand: `auth` is only one level above `login_view`, why the `..` and not `.`?

This also fails with the same error:

```
from .. import auth
```

In `test.py` I tried the following:

```
import types
from .. import *

def imports():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            print 'imported: ', val.__name__

imports()
```

which results in:

```
imported:  lib.utils
imported:  lib.views
imported:  types
```

... I'm at a loss as to why `lib.auth` is not imported. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running the code as such (the abs. path is `/scratch/project/`):

```
$ cd project/
$ ./application.py
```

Comment: What directory are you running the code from?

Comment: @JaredSmith See edit.

Comment: "why the `..` and not `.`?"

Isn't `..` supposed to mean directory above, and `.` current directory?

Comment: @tungli: My understanding of http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports is that I need `..` to go up one directory.

Comment: well, yes, then `from ..auth import *` would mean go up one directory, into `auth`, import everything. just as in a file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a circular dependency one and not one of relative imports.

Indeed, `..` is needed to load a module from the parent directory.

However somewhere in `auth.py` I had an `import views.login_view`. I believe that the `from .. import auth` in `login_view.py` tried to import the `auth` module as it was being loaded itself. This is probably why `from ..auth import untoken` works because those functions had already been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `from . import auth` the `.` means the package `views`. That is why Python can't find it.

But, to avoid those problems is [recommended](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) that you use absolute import instead of relative imports.

Comment: Cheers, without the circular dependency, I tried replacing relative paths with absolute ones and it works well too.

Answer (score 1):

In Python a single dot in import represents the current **package**, NOT the current module.

Then every additional dot represents a new level of "parentness" (ok this word does not exist but I think it expresses well what I mean).
So the behaviour you notice in your first case is just normal.

For your second case, I to reproduced your hierarchy with those contents:

**application.py**

```
lib.views import login_view

print("oh yeah")
```

**login_view.py**

```
lib.views import login_view

print("oh my god")
```

... and running application.py from the project directory does not cause any error. I get the following output:

```
$ python application.py 
oh my god
oh yeah
```

---

However, adding a `from lib.views import test` (using the exact same `test.py` content you provided) in the `application.py` gives me the following output showing that some `lib` modules are not loaded:

```
$ python application.py 
oh my god
imported:  types
imported:  lib.views
imported:  lib.auth
oh yeah
```

The `lib.utils` module is missing :/

What I think is that since `from .. import *` names nothing: no package, no module, no function or variable or anything, the import statement simply imports nothing. TH displayed modules/packages are only the one which have been loaded earlier.

That said, there is a way to force a "correct" behaviour by using the `__all__` magic variable, which defines which modules are loaded when using the splat import, in the `lib/__init__.py` file:

```
__all__ = ['auth', 'views', 'utils']
```

After doing this, running again the `application.py` file shows the following:

```
$ python application.py 
oh my god
imported:  types
imported:  lib.auth
imported:  lib.views
imported:  lib.utils
oh yeah
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you went up 1 more directory when importing?

```
from ... import auth
```

Comment: `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`